# How to get notified when an attribute is updated in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, delegates

I have two async methods that fetch the data from an API. One updates the attribute of `earthLocationData`, the second one uses an attribute (`imageURL`) of `earthLocationData` to download an image that will be saved on `earthLocationData.image`.

Once the image is downloaded I should change the imageView with that image.

I have this code:

```
var earthLocationData: EarthLocationData? {
    didSet {
        self.imageView.image = earthLocationData!.image
    }
}
```

but it does not work because the `earthLocationData.image` is downloaded in an async way.

So is there a way to use the didSet on `earthLocationData.image`?

Comment: How do you download `earthLocationData.image`? Please share full code.

Comment: You can either use a delegation pattern, or provide a callback closure to your `EarthLocationData` object, or you can use NSNotification.

Comment: If `earthLocationData.image` is being loaded on a different thread, your callback is happening on that same thead. Any UI updates need to happen on the main thread so wrap the `self.imageView.image` code in `DispatchQueue.main.async`